# Where is the Lubuntu 19.04 auto-login?

Tags: lubuntu, login

During installation of Lubuntu 19.04, there is an option to *Log in automatically without asking for the password*.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't find this setting anymore after installation.

I searched on the net but couldn't find any similar issues.

E.g. https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/enable-lubuntu-auto-login/

is for *12.04* or lower and there is no directory named */etc/lxdm/* or */etc/lightdm/* in *19.04*.

https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu/

is for Ubuntu and there is no *Automatic Login* setting in *User Accounts*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a section in the Lubuntu manual that deals with this :-

https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html

> **Chapter 3.1.9 SDDM configuration**
>
> Sddm is the display manager that shows up when you first log in to
>   Lubuntu or logout or choose to another session. This has no graphical
>   application to do this.
>
> **Usage**
>
> If you have autologin enabled and want to disable autologin open
>   the file /etc/sddm.conf as root. To do this run
>
> `lxqt-sudo featherpad` and open `/etc/sddm.conf`. Then to disable
>   autologin remove the entire line [autologin].

To enable auto-login, you do the reverse (ie. add the line) but I would suggest reading it in the manual  (*it's better formatted than I can do*)